# Instantiation of function required here, but no definition found

Tags: c++

I have a function that takes iterators and a lambda function as parameters and than calls all_off method with this arguments.
But, when I call my function in main.cpp, I have linker error: Instantiation of function required here, but no definition found.
My code:

func.h:

```
#pragma once

namespace func
{
    template <class It, class Pred>
    bool all(It itBegin, It itEnd, Pred pred);
}
```

func.cpp:

```
#include "func.h"

#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <execution>
#include <iostream>

namespace func
{
    template <class It, class Pred>
    bool all(It itBegin, It itEnd, Pred pred)
    {
        // some code
        return std::all_off(itBegin, itEnd, pred);
    }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "func.h"

int main
{
    auto isPositive = [](const auto &v) { return v > 0; };
    std::vector<int> testData1k(1000, 1);
    std::cout << std::thread::hardware_concurrency() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::distance(testData1k.begin(), testData1k.end());

    // Here is warning
    func::all<std::vector<int>::iterator>(testData1k.begin(), testData1k.end(), isPositive); 
}
```